# Doing tree search in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, pathfinding, breadth-first-search

I have this tiny library for building unbalanced, binary trees and doing tree search on them. I tried hard to define a generic API that would allow custom implementations of trees.

**AbstractBinaryTreeNode.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.graph.tree;

/**
 * This class defines the API for a binary tree node.
 * 
 * @author Rodion Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 * @param <E> the type of satellite data.
 * @param <N> the actual node implementation type.
 */
public abstract class
        AbstractBinaryTreeNode<E extends Comparable<? super E>, 
                               N extends AbstractBinaryTreeNode<E, N>> {

    /**
     * Stores the satellite datum of this node.
     */
    protected final E element;

    /**
     * The left child node.
     */
    protected N left;

    /**
     * The right child node.
     */
    protected N right;

    /**
     * Constructs a new binary tree node with <code>element</code> as the 
     * satellite datum.
     * 
     * @param element the satellite datum.
     */
    public AbstractBinaryTreeNode(final E element) {
        checkNotNull(element);
        this.element = element;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the element of this node.
     * 
     * @return the element of this node.
     */
    public E getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the left child node.
     * 
     * @return the left child node.
     */
    public N getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the right child node.
     * 
     * @return the right child node.
     */
    public N getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    /**
     * Checks that the input element is not <code>null</code>.
     * 
     * @param element the element to check.
     */
    private void checkNotNull(final E element) {
        if (element == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException(
                    "The element for a " + getClass().getSimpleName() + 
                    " is null.");
        }
    }
}
```

**AbstractTreeNodeFinder.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.graph.tree;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

/**
 * This abstract class defines the API for tree search algorithms.
 * 
 * @author Rodion Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 * @param <N> the type of nodes being searched.
 */
public abstract class 
        AbstractTreeNodeFinder<N extends AbstractBinaryTreeNode<?, N>>
{
    /**
     * Initiates the search from <code>source</code> and stops the search at 
     * a node which passes the input predicate. The path from 
     * <code>source</code> to the goal node is returned. If the goal node is 
     * not reachable, an empty list is returned.
     * 
     * @param  source            the source state.
     * @param  goalNodePredicate the predicate for recognizing goal nodes.
     * @return the list describing a path from a source to a goal node.
     */
    public abstract List<N> search(final N source,
                                   final Predicate<N> goalNodePredicate);

    /**
     * Constructs a shortest path.
     * 
     * @param goal      the goal node.
     * @param parentMap the map mapping a node to its parent node in the tree.
     * @return a path.
     */
    protected List<N> tracebackPath(final N goal, final Map<N, N> parentMap) {
        final List<N> path = new ArrayList<>();
        N current = goal;

        while (current != null) {
            path.add(current);
            current = parentMap.get(current);
        }

        Collections.<N>reverse(path);
        return path;
    }
}
```

**BinaryTree.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.graph.tree;

/**
 * This class implements a simple, unbalanced binary tree.
 * 
 * @author Rodion Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 * @param <E> the type of satellite data.
 */
public class BinaryTree<E extends Comparable<? super E>> {

    /**
     * This class holds the actual satellite datum and possible links to child
     * tree nodes. This inner static class is declared public so that other 
     * algorithms can work on them.
     * 
     * @param <E> the type of the satellite datum.
     */
    public static final class BinaryTreeNode<E extends Comparable<? super E>> 
    extends AbstractBinaryTreeNode<E, BinaryTreeNode<E>> {

        /**
         * Construct a new tree node with given element.
         * 
         * @param element the element to store in this tree node.
         */
        BinaryTreeNode(final E element) {
            super(element);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the satellite datum of this tree node.
         * 
         * @return the satellite datum.
         */
        public E getElement() {
            return element;
        }
    }

    /**
     * The root node of this tree.
     */
    private BinaryTreeNode<E> root;

    /**
     * Adds a new element to this tree.
     * 
     * @param element the element to add. 
     */
    public void add(final E element) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new BinaryTreeNode<>(element);
            return;
        }

        BinaryTreeNode<E> parent = null;
        BinaryTreeNode<E> current = root;

        while (current != null) {
            parent = current;
            current = element.compareTo(current.element) < 0 ?
                      current.left :
                      current.right;
        }

        if (element.compareTo(parent.element) < 0) {
            parent.left = new BinaryTreeNode<>(element);
        } else {
            parent.right = new BinaryTreeNode<>(element);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the root node of this tree.
     * 
     * @return the root node.
     */
    public BinaryTreeNode<E> getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the node containing <code>element</code> or <code>null</code> if
     * there is no such node.
     * 
     * @param  element the target element.
     * @return the tree node or <code>null</code>.
     */
    public BinaryTreeNode<E> getNode(final E element) {
        BinaryTreeNode<E> current = root;

        while (current != null) {
            if (current.getElement().equals(element)) {
                return current;
            }

            current = element.compareTo(current.getElement()) < 0 ?
                      current.left :
                      current.right;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**BreadthFirstSearchNodeFinder.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.graph.tree.support;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import net.coderodde.graph.tree.AbstractBinaryTreeNode;
import net.coderodde.graph.tree.AbstractTreeNodeFinder;

/**
 * This class implements breadth-first search for trees.
 * 
 * @author Rodion Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 * @param <N> the actual binary tree node type.
 */
public class BreadthFirstSearchNodeFinder<N extends AbstractBinaryTreeNode<?, N>>
extends AbstractTreeNodeFinder<N> {

    /**
     * Searches for a shortest path in a binary tree using breadth-first search.
     * 
     * @param source            the source node.
     * @param goalNodePredicate the goal node predicate.
     * @return                  the path from <code>source</code> to a goal 
     *                          node.
     */ 
    @Override
    public List<N> search(final N source, 
                          final Predicate<N> goalNodePredicate) {
        if (source == null) {
            // 'path' is empty, thus denoting a non-existent path.
            return new ArrayList<>(0);
        }

        final Deque<N> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
        final Map<N, N> parentMap = new HashMap<>();

        queue.addLast(source);
        parentMap.put(source, null);

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            final N current = queue.poll();

            if (goalNodePredicate.test(current)) {
                return tracebackPath(current, parentMap);
            }

            final N left  = current.getLeft();
            final N right = current.getRight();

            if (left != null) {
                queue.addLast(left);
                parentMap.put(left, current);
            }

            if (right != null) {
                queue.addLast(right);
                parentMap.put(right, current);
            }
        }

        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

**DepthFirstSearchNodeFinder.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.graph.tree.support;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import net.coderodde.graph.tree.AbstractBinaryTreeNode;
import net.coderodde.graph.tree.AbstractTreeNodeFinder;

/**
 * This class implements a depth-first search for finding paths from source 
 * nodes to goal nodes.
 * 
 * @author Rodion Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 * @param <N> the actual type of a tree node.
 */
public class DepthFirstSearchNodeFinder<N extends AbstractBinaryTreeNode<?, N>>
extends AbstractTreeNodeFinder<N> {

    /**
     * Searches for a shortest path from <code>source</code> to any node 
     * satisfying the <code>goalNodePredicate</code>.
     * 
     * @param source            the source node.
     * @param goalNodePredicate the goal node predicate.
     * @return                  a path.
     */
    @Override
    public List<N> search(final N source, 
                          final Predicate<N> goalNodePredicate) {
        if (source == null) {
            // 'path' is empty, thus denoting a non-existent path.
            return new ArrayList<>(0);
        }

        int bestLength = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        List<N> shortestPath = new ArrayList<>();

        final Deque<N> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        final Map<N, N> parentMap = new HashMap<>();

        stack.addLast(source);
        parentMap.put(source, null);

        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            final N current = stack.removeLast();

            if (goalNodePredicate.test(current)) {
                final List<N> path = tracebackPath(current, parentMap);

                if (bestLength > path.size()) {
                    bestLength = path.size();
                    shortestPath = path;
                }
            }

            final N left  = current.getLeft();
            final N right = current.getRight();

            if (left != null) {
                stack.addLast(left);
                parentMap.put(left, current);
            }

            if (right != null) {
                stack.addLast(right);
                parentMap.put(right, current);
            }
        }

        return shortestPath;
    }
}
```

**IDDFSNodeFinder.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.graph.tree.support;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import net.coderodde.graph.tree.AbstractBinaryTreeNode;
import net.coderodde.graph.tree.AbstractTreeNodeFinder;

/**
 * This class implements the IDDFS algorithm (iterative deepening depth-first
 * search) described in 
 * <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search">Wikipedia</a>.
 * 
 * @author Rodion Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 * @param <N> the actual type of a tree node.
 */
public class IDDFSNodeFinder<N extends AbstractBinaryTreeNode<?, N>> 
extends AbstractTreeNodeFinder<N> {

    private int previousReachedNodes;
    private int reachedNodes;

    @Override
    public List<N> search(final N source, 
                          final Predicate<N> goalNodePredicate) {
        if (source == null) {
            // 'path' is empty, thus denoting a non-existent path.
            return new ArrayList<>(0);
        }

        final Map<N, N> parentMap = new HashMap<>();
        parentMap.put(source, null);

        previousReachedNodes = 0;
        reachedNodes = 0;

        for (int depth = 0;; ++depth) {
            final N found = dls(source, 
                                depth, 
                                parentMap,
                                goalNodePredicate);

            if (found != null) {
                return tracebackPath(found, parentMap);
            }

            if (reachedNodes == previousReachedNodes) {
                // We have reached all the nodes of the tree and we did not find
                // any goal node.
                return new ArrayList<>(0);
            }

            previousReachedNodes = reachedNodes;
            reachedNodes = 0;
        }
    }

    private N dls(final N node, 
                  final int depth,
                  final Map<N, N> parentMap,
                  final Predicate<N> goalNodePredicate) {
        ++reachedNodes;

        if (depth == 0) {
            return goalNodePredicate.test(node) ? node : null;
        }

        N found;

        if (node.getLeft() != null) {
            found = dls(node.getLeft(),
                        depth - 1, 
                        parentMap,
                        goalNodePredicate);

            parentMap.put(node.getLeft(), node);

            if (found != null) {
                return found;
            }
        }

        if (node.getRight() != null) {
            found = dls(node.getRight(), 
                        depth - 1, 
                        parentMap,
                        goalNodePredicate);

            parentMap.put(node.getRight(), node);

            if (found != null) {
                return found;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**App.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.graph.tree;

import net.coderodde.graph.tree.support.BreadthFirstSearchNodeFinder;
import net.coderodde.graph.tree.support.DepthFirstSearchNodeFinder;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import net.coderodde.graph.tree.BinaryTree.BinaryTreeNode;
import net.coderodde.graph.tree.support.IDDFSNodeFinder;

public class App {

    /**
     * The minimum key value.
     */
    private static final int MINIMUM = -10000;

    /**
     * The maximum key value.
     */
    private static final int MAXIMUM = 100000;

    /**
     * The size of the tree.
     */
    private static final int SIZE = 1000000;

    /**
     * The entry point into a program.

     * @param args the command line arguments.
     */
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final long seed = System.currentTimeMillis(); //1431245853421L;
        final Random rnd = new Random(seed);
        final BinaryTree<Integer> tree = createRandomBinaryTree(SIZE,
                                                                MINIMUM,
                                                                MAXIMUM,
                                                                rnd);
        final Integer target = rnd.nextInt(MAXIMUM - MINIMUM + 10) + 
                               MINIMUM - 5;

        System.out.println("Seed:   " + seed);
        System.out.println("Root:   " + tree.getRoot().getElement());
        System.out.println("Target: " + target);
        System.out.println();

        final Predicate<BinaryTreeNode<Integer>> gp = 
        (final BinaryTreeNode<Integer> t) -> t.getElement().equals(target);

        final List<BinaryTreeNode<Integer>> path1 = 
        profileFinder(new DepthFirstSearchNodeFinder<>(), gp, tree.getRoot());

        final List<BinaryTreeNode<Integer>> path2 = 
        profileFinder(new BreadthFirstSearchNodeFinder<>(), gp, tree.getRoot());

        final List<BinaryTreeNode<Integer>> path3 = 
        profileFinder(new IDDFSNodeFinder<>(), gp, tree.getRoot());

        System.out.println("Paths equal: " + listsEqual(path1, path2, path3));
        System.out.println();

        printPath(path1, "DFS path:");

        System.out.println();

        printPath(path2, "BFS path:");

        System.out.println();

        printPath(path3, "IDDFS path:");
    }

    /**
     * Checks that all input lists are of the same length and content.
     * 
     * @param <T>   the list component type.
     * @param lists the array of lists.
     * @return <code>true</code> if and only if the lists are same.
     */
    public static <T> boolean listsEqual(final List<T>... lists) {
        if (lists.length < 2) {
            // Trivially equal.
            return true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < lists.length - 1; ++i) {
            if (lists[i].size() != lists[i + 1].size()) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (lists[0].isEmpty()) {
            // All are empty.
            return true;
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < lists[0].size(); ++index) {
            for (int i = 0; i < lists.length - 1; ++i) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < lists.length; ++j) {
                    if (!lists[i].get(index).equals(lists[j].get(index))) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Prints the path.
     * 
     * @param path  the path to print.
     * @param title the title message.
     */
    private static void printPath(final List<BinaryTreeNode<Integer>> path,
                                  final String title) {
        System.out.println(title);

        path.stream().forEach((node) -> {
            System.out.println(node.getElement());
        });
    }

    /**
     * Profiles the input finder, prints its time usage and returns its result
     * path.
     * 
     * @param finder        the finder implementation.
     * @param goalPredicate the goal node predicate.
     * @param source        the source node.
     * @return a tree path.
     */
    private static List<BinaryTreeNode<Integer>> 
    profileFinder(final AbstractTreeNodeFinder<BinaryTreeNode
                                               <Integer>> finder,
                  final Predicate<BinaryTreeNode<Integer>> goalPredicate,
                  final BinaryTreeNode<Integer> source) {
        final long ta = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final List<BinaryTreeNode<Integer>> path = 
                finder.search(source, goalPredicate);
        final long tb = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println(finder.getClass().getSimpleName() + 
                           " in " + (tb - ta) + " ms.");

        return path;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a binary integer tree with integers within range
     * <tt>[minimum, maximum]</tt>.
     * 
     * @param size    the amount of values to create in the tree.
     * @param minimum the minimum value.
     * @param maximum the maximum value.
     * @param rnd     the random number generator.
     * @return        a random binary tree.
     */
    private static BinaryTree<Integer> 
        createRandomBinaryTree(final int size,
                               final int minimum,
                               final int maximum,
                               final Random rnd) {
        final BinaryTree<Integer> tree = new BinaryTree<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            tree.add(rnd.nextInt(maximum - minimum + 1) + minimum);
        }

        return tree;
    }
}
```

Any improvements I could do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the whole, your code is neat, the style is good, generics look OK. I have a concern with two major 'design' points though.

The first is the `AbstractBinaryTreeNode` class. This encapsulates the basic functionality of a node in the binary tree, and it makes it seem that there would be a way to customize the implementation.

Unfortunately, you can't.

Your BinaryTree class creates a concrete implementation as a static-internal:

> ```
> public static final class BinaryTreeNode<E extends Comparable<? super E>> 
>    extends AbstractBinaryTreeNode<E, BinaryTreeNode<E>> {
> ```

and then only uses this implementation for the root:

> ```
> /**
>  * The root node of this tree.
>  */
> private BinaryTreeNode<E> root;
> ```

Thus the whole thing is moot, and redundant.

The other issue I see is in the `AbstractTreeNodeFinder`. This has two problems.

The first problem is the concrete method `tracebackPath`, which has lousy JavaDoc, so I am not sure of its purpose, but the implementation reads like a static method...

I would consider removing that class entirely, and reducing it to a `@FunctionalInterface`, and then you can pass it in for each search.

There's abstraction overkill in there.